# Inserting records directly into a star schema

Tags: schema, reporting, data-warehouse

We have a simple site on which a small number of employees log when they have completed a task. 
Descriptive attributes of the task are Location, complexity, date, Supervision level & a score is calculated.

Although volumes are low, the main use of this data is reporting.

As the schema is relatively simple & volumes low, i can easily store this directly into a star schema.

Is there any reason i should not directly load the data into a star schema?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, simpler 'relational' schemas look like dimensional models. After all, you're always going to log events, and always have tables to store descriptive context to the events.

If there are limited or no relationships between the descriptive attributes of your tasks, and you don't see the overall model evolving into something more complex, I see no reason to load it into anything other than a star schema. The attributes are 'about tasks', so the model is correct in a relational model or star schema.

You could always call it a relational schema if you like- it just happens to be simple enough to look like a star!

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts: direct loading is good only for relatively small data size. But if in future the number of employees / tasks increase by a huge amount then loading directly could be very counterproductive and error prone.

So it is better to plan these things ahead and have processes which can be scaled easily in future if the load increases.